# Spark write (parquet) to on-premises HDFS taking long time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

**Context:**

I have a very simple scala/spark job where I READ data from a table in a Microsoft SQL Server relational database through SPARK JDBC READ. The read data goes to a DataFrame and then I use "df.write.option("compression", "snappy").parquet(outputDir)" to write these data to an on-premises HDFS.

**Problem:**

The table is very small (less than 1GB of size), but it is taking 2.2h to read & write to HDFS.
I already tried to DISABLE write and read was really fast, in other words, writing is the problem here.

**Tentatives:**

- Already tried with big (92gb) and small (900mb) datasets. Time to write was very similar
- Already tried to change commiter algorithm version from 1 to 2 "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2"
- Already tried to remove the parquet _SUCCESS file creation
  "mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false"
- I'm already using "spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"

**Spark Submit Configs:**

```
"spark.executor.instances": 20
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": 1000,
"spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec": "snappy",
"spark.port.maxRetries": 1000,
"spark.sql.broadcastTimeout": 36000,
"spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC",
"spark.driver.maxResultSize": "32G",
"spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts": 1,
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
"spark.driver.cores": 1,
"spark.driver.memory": "20G",
"spark.driver.memoryOverhead": "2G",
"spark.executor.cores": 4,
"spark.executor.memory": "10G",
"spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "1G",
"spark.network.timeout": 360000,
"spark.executor.heartbeatInterval": 288000,
"spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version": 2,
"spark.hadoop.mapred.output.committer.class": "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter",
"spark.hadoop.mapreduce.use.directfileoutputcommitter": "true",
"spark.hadoop.mapreduce.use.parallelmergepaths": "true",
"mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs": "false"
```

**Some code details:**

Method that writes the data to HDFS

```
df.write
  .mode(saveMode)
  .option("compression","snappy")
  .parquet(source.sourceOutputDir)
```

**Versions:**

- Scala 2.11.2
- Spark 2.4.0

**Obs:**

- There is no JOIN in the code
- Its only READ to DataFrame & Write to HDFS

Comment: My hunch it is due to the shuffle partitions settings. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804610/spark-shuffle-write-is-super-slow) should hopefully have some helpful information. In particular, it suggests adding a `repartition`.

Comment: did the above link help? If so you could [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the Spark UI to identify where the problem actually is?  Are you using EC2/S3